# SQL statement with PHP - Select the latest added row from each vendor

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This question is probably easy to solve, but here it comes.

I would like to get the latest data from each vendor (the latest row inserted into the database for each vendor).

This is some sample data from MySQL:

```
id  vendorId  vendor   url          delay   price0   price1   price2   price3   price4   price5   price6     date
1   1         vendor1  vendor1.com    0       12       15       18       14       25       28       25       2012-01-18 09:43:40
2   2         vendor2  vendor2.com    0       12       15       18       14       25       28       25       2012-01-18 09:43:40
3   1         vendor1  vendor1.com    0       15       17       122      12       30       52       53       2012-01-18 10:02:40
4   2         vendor2  vendor2.com    0       13       12       123      16       54       61       91       2012-01-18 10:02:40
```

I would like the output to be:

```
id  vendorId  vendor   url          delay   price0   price1    price2   price3   price4   price5   price6     date
3   1         vendor1  vendor1.com    0       15       17       122       12       30       52       53       2012-01-18 10:02:40
4   2         vendor2  vendor2.com    0       13       12       123       16       54       61       91       2012-01-18 10:02:40
```

What would the SQL be and how would I put the values into this array?

```
$vendor = array(
       array('vendorId' => '1', 'vendor' => 'vendor1', 'url' => 'vendor1', 'delay' => 0, 'price0' => 12, 'price1' => 15, 'price2' => 26, 'price3' => 14, 'price4' => 25, 'price5' => 64, 'price6' => 512),
       array('vendorId' => '2', 'vendor' => 'vendor2', 'url' => 'vendor2', 'delay' => 0, 'price0' => 12, 'price1' => 15, 'price2' => 26, 'price3' => 14, 'price4' => 25, 'price5' => 64, 'price6' => 512)
);
```

Thanks in advance

Also, I forgot to mention: There will be more than just 2 vendors in the database, so I'd prefer that they'd be picked up per auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT max( id ) AS max_id, vendorId, url, delay, 
price0, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6, date 
FROM `vendors` 
GROUP BY vendorId
```

You updated your question with how you should obtain the resultset into an array.
Refer here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

You will then be able to add each row as an associative array to another array containing all your vendors, accessible by key/value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've got all the values just as I wanted, still confused when it comes to adding the vendors into my own multidimensional array. I've come to this while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
}

Comment: From there it's just as simple to add the arrays into your vendor array, just add the following inside your curly braces {}: $vendor_array[] = $r;

Comment: One thing though - the sql seem to be picking up the rows added first, instead of the latest added rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: This SQL statement might appear to work on some occasion, but it is very much dependant on the order of the records in the database, as there is different values for the prices field. Basically the database might randomly choose the record to return. The record returned might change if you compact the database, or somehow change the physical sort order of the records in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT v1.* FROM vendors v1
  JOIN (
    SELECT vendorId, MAX(date) date FROM vendors GROUP BY vendorId
  ) v2
ON v1.vendorId = v2.vendorId AND v1.date = v2.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the syntax is correct, but this is roughly how I would do it.

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `vendorId`, `vendor`, `url`, `delay`, `price0`, 
    `price1`, `price2`, `price3`, `price4`, `price5`, 
    `price6`, `date` 
FROM 
    `vendor_table_name` 
GROUP BY 
    `vendor_id` 
HAVING 
    `date` = max(`date`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
select * from vendor_table_name as ts 
left join 
(select max(id) as id from vendor_table_name group by vendorId) as tsm
on ts.id=tsm.id
```

However it has limit after that it will be slow approx after 50K - 80K rows

Best way is to make a view for latest records and make join with view.

like below :

```
  create view latestrecords as 
  select max(id) as id,vendorId from vendor_table_name group by vendorId
```

and do join with view :

```
  select * from vendor_table_name as ts 
    left join 
    latestrecords  as tsm
    on ts.id=tsm.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would my mysql query look like with your example?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM vendor_table_name ORDER BY date DESC
```

For the array

```
$result =  (query result)

foreach($result as $r){
     $array = array("name" => $r->name, .....);
}
```

Comment: This will only return the information sorted by date, but will not filter out ONLY the latest record for each vendor.